# составление линейных программ на языке Pascal

Tags: pascal, формулы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]всем привет. Запутался в скобках или что-то не так делаю? смысл в том что бы создать 2 программы по формуле.

[image: задание]
[image: мой вариант 17го]

```
program example2;
var x,y,z,b:real;
begin
writeln('vvedite x,y,z');
readln (x,y,z);
b:=ln (sqrt(exp(x-y))+x(abs(y))+z);
write ('funkciya b ravna b=',b:10:4);                                                                                                                                                                                               
readln
end
```

Comment: внесите `z` под корень

Comment: а разве он уже не под корнем? последняя скобка и первая это всё корень

Comment: Нет, у вас ln(sqrt(...) + z), z не под корнем.

Comment: нет, первая и последняя скобки - это логарифм

Comment: я добавил 2 скобки. Правильно?

Comment: вот эта запись что значит `x(abs(y))`?

Comment: оу. там должен быть exp. тк там x в степени |x|

Comment: нет, там должна быть функция `power`

Comment: и `z` все еще не под корнем

Comment: как это написать? я не у нас про power ни слова не говорили. отредактируйте пожалуйста ln(sqrt((exp(x-y))+(x(exp(abs(y)))+z))

Comment: `lg` - десятичный логарифм, `ln` - натуральный. Ну и публикуйте код, а не скриншоты

Comment: если перед корнем поставить lg, пишет неправильный индентификатор

Comment: никто больше не поможет?

Comment: `x(abs(y))` - знак "умножить" пропущен

Answer (score 0):

```
PROGRAM laba;

USES crt;

VAR
    b, x, y, z: real;

BEGIN
    x := 0.100;
    y := -8.750;

    b := y + x / (y + x * x / (y + x * x * x / y));
    WriteLn(b:10:7);
    // -8.7614271


    x := 1.542;
    y := -8.261;
    z := 80.005;

    b := LN(SQRT(EXP(x - y) + EXP(ABS(y) * LN(x)) + z)) / LN(10);
    WriteLn(b:10:7);
    //  2.1300801
END.
```

Comment: спасибо большое. Поменял в своём коде строку с b на эту: 
b := LN(SQRT(EXP(x - y) + EXP(ABS(y) * LN(x)) + z)) / LN(10); и всё заработало...

Comment: @Kamikaze если помогло, то можно отметить как решение, галочка слева от ответа